# How to find variance within and between batches

Tags: r, variance, frequentist

I have some data for 5 different batches of bacteria counts with 5 observations each -

- Batch 1: 3.890, 4.675, 7.345, 2.950, 5.675
- Batch 2: 4.345, 5.875, 3.665, 2.935, 5.455
- Batch 3: 7.145, 5.550, 6.445, 6.890, 4.985
- Batch 4: 2.675, 3.450, 4.125, 3.875, 5.125
- Batch 5: 3.350, 7.155, 6.255, 6.440, 4.960

I am trying to find the variance within each of the 5 batches, as well as the variance *between* the 5 batches collectively (will be using R for ease of calculations).

I'm not entirely sure how to go about doing this. Using R isn't a problem, I just don't fully understand how to actually calculate the variance parameters.

```
b1=c(3.890, 4.675, 7.345, 2.950, 5.675)
b2=c(4.345, 5.875, 3.665, 2.935, 5.455)
b3=c(7.145, 5.550, 6.445, 6.890, 4.985)
b4=c(2.675, 3.450, 4.125, 3.875, 5.125)
b5=c(3.350, 7.155, 6.255, 6.440, 4.960)

var_within_batches = c(var(b1),var(b2),var(b3),var(b4),var(b5))
for (k in 1:5){
print(var_within_batches[k])}
```

This gives a result of

```
[1] 2.862907
[1] 1.49075
[1] 0.8319575
[1] 0.810625
[1] 2.254908
```

This should be the variance within each individual batch, and then we do

```
mean(var_within_batches)
[1] 1.650229
```

and this should be the parameter estimate for variance within batches, right?

---

The calculation for variance between batches is also confusing me. Is it either of these? I'm a bit lost. Thanks for any help!

```
between_batch_var_guess1 = var(var_within_batches)
[1] 0.8090405

between_batch_var_guess2 = sum(var_within_batches)/5
[1] 1.65023
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Computing Mean Squares from data.** When batches have equal sample sizes and equal population variances $\sigma^2,$
MS(Residual) is the average of the batch variances, as you have. MS(Residual) estimates $\sigma^2$ whether or not the null hypothesis (that all batches have the same mean) is true.

```
b1=c(3.890, 4.675, 7.345, 2.950, 5.675)
b2=c(4.345, 5.875, 3.665, 2.935, 5.455)
b3=c(7.145, 5.550, 6.445, 6.890, 4.985)
b4=c(2.675, 3.450, 4.125, 3.875, 5.125)
b5=c(3.350, 7.155, 6.255, 6.440, 4.960)

(var(b1) + var(b2) + var(b3) + var(b4) + var(b5))/5
[1] 1.65023
```

If the null hypothesis is true and the common batch mean is $\mu,$ then
each batch mean is an observation from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma^2/5).$
Then, the variance of the five batch means estimates $\sigma^2/5.$
Thus, the following quantity, MS(batch), estimates $\sigma^2$ under the null hypothesis.

```
5 * var(c(mean(b1),mean(b2),mean(b3),mean(b4),mean(b5)))
[1] 4.342956
```

Then the F-ratio for testing the null hypothesis is $F = 4.343/1.650 = 2.632,$ with
$DF_1 = 4, DF_4 = 20.$

---

**ANOVA computations in R.** However, because you have the data, it may be best just to use R to do the one-way ANOVA.

```
x = c(b1,b2,b3,b4,b5)
b = as.factor(rep(1:5, each=5))
anova(lm(x ~ b))
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: x
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
b          4 17.372  4.3430  2.6317 0.06481 .
Residuals 20 33.005  1.6502                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

***Heteroscedasticity:*** Moreover, because the batch variances seem to be quite different, it may be
best to do a version of the one-way ANOVA that does not assume equal variances.
[It uses a Satterthwaite approximation, similar to that of the Welch 2-sample
t test. The result is that the denominator degrees of freedom are decreased.]

```
oneway.test(x ~ b)

        One-way analysis of means (not assuming equal variances)

data:  x and b
F = 3.8952, num df = 4.0000, denom df = 9.8593, p-value = 0.03756
```

---

**Interpretation.** Here are boxplots of the five batches. If batches are use different processes
you may want to try to explore differences among batch means with *ad hoc* tests,
but you should use some method of avoiding 'false discovery'--especially
because the ANOVA is significant only at about the 4% level. At least, it does seem safe to say that batches 3 and 4 are significantly different.

```
t.test(b3, b4)$p.val  # Welch t test
[1] 0.003413997

boxplot(x ~ b, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

Boxplots of samples of size five must be interpreted carefully: each of the five
observations may correspond to one of: minimum, Q1, median, Q3, and maximum.
The ends of the boxes are at Q1 and Q3.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, this was really insightful!